# Unknown-type artifacts with OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I'm learning to use OpenGL for game development. My main.c file contains relatively few code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "main.h"

void framebufferSizeCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferSizeCallback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processInput(window);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile and run it, artifacts appear for reasons I don't know:

[image]

Those are probably parts of the screen being kept in memory and displayed where they shouldn't be, and I'd want to know how I can get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the line `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);` after creating the window. This should set the OpenGL context being used to the one the `window` variable is displaying.